# Barplot/Histogram with matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, histogram

I am trying to achieve a simple barplot/histogram, however, the output is empty:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df["Subject_Age"] = X["Subject.Age"]

bins = [0, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 100]

labels = ['0 - 15', '16 - 25', '26 - 35', '36 - 45', '46 - 55', '56 - 65', '66 - 75', '76+']

binned_values = np.histogram(df['Subject_Age'], bins=bins)[0].tolist()

df_hist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(labels, binned_values)), orient='index').reset_index()

binned_values = np.histogram(df['Subject_Age'], bins=bins)[0].tolist()

df_hist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(labels, binned_values)), orient='index').reset_index()

df_hist.columns = ['Age range', 'Counts']

sn.barplot(data = df, x = 'Age range', y = 'Counts', palette = 'rocket',
           ci = 'sd', 
order = ['0-15', '16-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56-65', '66-75', '76+']);
```

Which results in an empty barplot:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbPrE.png)

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Maybe you meant `sns.barplot(data=df_hist, ....)`?  Also note that your `labels` and `order` lists are using different spacing except for `76+`.  It would be recommended to directly use the same list, as in `sns.barplot(...., order=labels)`.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC solved by setting `orders=labels`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import pandas as pd

bins = [0, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 100]
labels = ['0 - 15', '16 - 25', '26 - 35', '36 - 45', '46 - 55', '56 - 65', '66 - 75', '76+']

df = pd.DataFrame()
# Data example
df['Age'] = [5, 10, 12, 18, 23, 26, 27, 28, 36, 46, 47, 49, 50, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 67, 67, 80, 89, 89, 88, 91]

df_count = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels).value_counts(sort=False)
df_count.plot.bar(y='Age', use_index=True).figure.show()
```

Comment: `pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels).value_counts(sort=False)`  is indeed better code, but it leads to different counts than with the numpy solution. Got an idea why?

Comment: According to the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

"If bins is a sequence, it defines a monotonically increasing array of bin edges, including the rightmost edge", so, the bin values will be included to the right. Based on my data example, the NumPy version (using the same bins) puts the 55 on the "56 - 65" bucket. Just for clarification, you can check this behavior by repeating 55 on list.